# PHP MySQL UPDATE - no errors, but not updating

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am having trouble with what seems like it should be a simple MySQL update.  However when I check in phpMyAdmin, the row is not updating.  I have a table with columns:

| id | email | item1 | item2 | item3 |

- item1, item2, and item3 are all set to null.
- id is generated when the user enters their email as the user completes a task, their result is entered into the corresponding item column.
- Before they complete the task the code checks to see if they have done so by checking for a null value.
- If the value is null they can continue to the task, then it goes to this code to store the result.

  ```
  require("login.php");
  $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $id = "1";
  $name = "item1";
  $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $fileName);
  $sql = "UPDATE once SET ".$name." = '".$file."' WHERE id = ".$id;

  //I also tried:
  //$sql = "UPDATE once SET ".$name." = '".$file."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";

  echo $sql;
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  mysqli_close($connection);
  ```

I did an echo statement to show that this is what the $sql line is sending:

```
UPDATE once SET item1 = 'New File!' WHERE id = 1
```

(alternate with id = '1' also sent as expected)

I've checked other people's questions here and have tried altering mine to fit the accepted answers... but each time, phpMyAdmin continues to show no updates.  I am showing no errors in my error_log file any more and have no idea how to continue.

**UPDATE: Problem solved**
I used a person's nickname instead of their proper name in my table column... I feel pretty silly right now.

Lesson learned:  more error reporting!
This line saved me:

```
   echo $result ? 'good' : 'failed with ' . mysqli_error($connection);
```

Comment: Can you check the status of the query you executed? if($result){ echo "Query successful"; }... or something on those lines

Comment: After you do `$result = mysqli_query(...);`, add a line like so: `echo $result ? 'good' : 'failed with ' . mysqli_error($connection);`. If you get failed, that means the update statement is failing and you aren't catching that failure case.

Comment: Try to add  `mysqli_error($connection)`

Comment: oh... my... goodness... I feel so stupid.
The column I was writing to included a name... I used their nickname instead of their proper name.  It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `affected_rows` to see if something was updated:

```
$connection->affected_rows;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php